# Why the second move_uploaded_file function doesn't work in this code?

Tags: php

**How can I upload the thumbnail in this code?**
When I click upload, it only moves the first move_uploaded file and doesn't move the second one.
Can anyone help me, please?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $cap = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cap']);
    $image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $tmp_name= $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    $thumb = $_FILES['thumb'] ['name'];
    $tmp_name= $_FILES['thumb'] ['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    

    if(empty($image) or empty($thumb) or empty($cap)){
        $error = "<p style='font-seize: 20px; font-weight: bolder; color: red;'>
        Please Fill out all required stared inputs!</p>";
    }
    else{
        $pic = "INSERT INTO photos(image, thumb, caps, type)VALUES('$image', '$thumb', '$cap', '$type')";
        if(mysqli_query($con, $pic)){
            $success = "<p style='font-seize: 25px; font-weight: bolder; color: green;'>
            <i class='fa fa-smile-beam'></i> Your Data 
            Published Successfully</p>";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "img/photos/$image");
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "img/thumbs/$thumb");
            
        }
        else{
            $fail = "<p style='font-seize: 20px; font-weight: bolder; color: red;'><i class='fa fa-sad-tear'>
            </i> Unsuccessful!</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Once it was moved, copying from the original location is bound to fail. Because, well, it was moved from there.

Comment: Do the copy first, or copy `img/photos/$image`

Comment: @Barmar I mean, How can I move both images at the same time? Can you tell me more specifif?

Comment: @mario So how can I move both images at the same time to a directory?

Comment: You need to use different variables for the two images. You're using `$tmp_name` for both of them.

Comment: `$tmp_image` and `$tmp_thumb` for example.

Comment: @Barmar I think it worked. I just used copy for thefirst one and move_uploaded_file for the second one.

Comment: But you need to use different variables, otherwise you're copying and moving the same file.

Comment: tmp_name is a keyword for uploading files in PHP. if it replaced, it will show errors(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable can only hold one thing. You're using `$tmp_name` for both the image and thumb, and after the second assignment it just has the thumb's temp name.

You need to use different variables.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $cap = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cap']);
    $image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $tmp_image= $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    $thumb = $_FILES['thumb'] ['name'];
    $tmp_thumb= $_FILES['thumb'] ['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    

    if(empty($image) or empty($thumb) or empty($cap)){
        $error = "<p style='font-seize: 20px; font-weight: bolder; color: red;'>
        Please Fill out all required stared inputs!</p>";
    }
    else{
        $pic = "INSERT INTO photos(image, thumb, caps, type)VALUES('$image', '$thumb', '$cap', '$type')";
        if(mysqli_query($con, $pic)){
            $success = "<p style='font-seize: 25px; font-weight: bolder; color: green;'>
            <i class='fa fa-smile-beam'></i> Your Data 
            Published Successfully</p>";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_image, "img/photos/$image");
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_thumb, "img/thumbs/$thumb");
            
        }
        else{
            $fail = "<p style='font-seize: 20px; font-weight: bolder; color: red;'><i class='fa fa-sad-tear'>
            </i> Unsuccessful!</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```